# pandas how to add part of the data from the upper group to the beginning of the lower group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dataA = [["2005-1-20", "9:35", 5], ["2005-1-20", "9:40", 8], ["2005-1-20", "9:45", 7],
  ["2005-1-20","9:50", 4], ["2005-1-20", "9:55", 2],
  ["2005-1-23", "9:35", 2], ["2005-1-23", "9:40", 3], ["2005-1-23", "9:45", 4],
  ["2005-1-23","9:50", 4], ["2005-1-23", "9:55", 775],
  ["2005-1-29", "9:35", 12], ["2005-1-29", "9:40", 13], ["2005-1-29", "9:45", 14],
  ["2005-1-29","9:50", 14], ["2005-1-29", "9:55", 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["date", "min", "val"])

   date        min   val
0   2005-1-20   9:35    5
1   2005-1-20   9:40    8
2   2005-1-20   9:45    7
3   2005-1-20   9:50    4
4   2005-1-20   9:55    2
5   2005-1-23   9:35    2
6   2005-1-23   9:40    3
7   2005-1-23   9:45    4
8   2005-1-23   9:50    4
9   2005-1-23   9:55    775
10  2005-1-29   9:35    12
11  2005-1-29   9:40    13
12  2005-1-29   9:45    14
13  2005-1-29   9:50    14
14  2005-1-29   9:55    15
```

group by date ,I want to add part of the data from the upper group to the beginning of the lower group,
result like this:

```
    date        min   val
0   2005-1-20   9:35    5
1   2005-1-20   9:40    8
2   2005-1-20   9:45    7
3   2005-1-20   9:50    4
4   2005-1-20   9:55    2
5   2005-1-23   9:25    4  -----> from uper group: 2005-1-20    9:50    4   changed date and min
6   2005-1-23   9:30    2  -----> from uper group: 2005-1-20    9:55    2   changed date and min
7   2005-1-23   9:35    2
8   2005-1-23   9:40    3
9   2005-1-23   9:45    4
10  2005-1-23   9:50    4
11  2005-1-23   9:55    775
12  2005-1-29   9:25    4  ----->  from uper group: 2005-1-23   9:50    4   changed date and min
13  2005-1-29   9:30    775  --->  from uper group: 2005-1-23   9:55    775  changed date and min
14  2005-1-29   9:35    12
15  2005-1-29   9:40    13
16  2005-1-29   9:45    14
17  2005-1-29   9:50    14
18  2005-1-29   9:55    15
........
```

the data is too huge, i can't copy it line by line, how to handle it in easy way ?

Comment: Can you explain, please, by what formula or principle these data should be added to another group?

Comment: the principle would be this: The last two data of each group，add to next group as beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try via `groupby()`,`append()`,`shift()` and `sort_values()`:

```
out=df.groupby('date',as_index=False).tail(2)
out.loc[:,'min']=['9:25','9:30']*int(len(out)/2)
out.loc[:,'date']=out.loc[:,'date'].shift(-2)
df=df.append(out).sort_values(['date','min'],ignore_index=True)
```

output of `df`:

```
    date        min     val
0   2005-1-20   9:35    5
1   2005-1-20   9:40    8
2   2005-1-20   9:45    7
3   2005-1-20   9:50    4
4   2005-1-20   9:55    2
5   2005-1-23   9:25    4  -----> from uper group: 2005-1-20    9:50    4   changed date and min
6   2005-1-23   9:30    2  -----> from uper group: 2005-1-20    9:55    2   changed date and min
7   2005-1-23   9:35    2
8   2005-1-23   9:40    3
9   2005-1-23   9:45    4
10  2005-1-23   9:50    4
11  2005-1-23   9:55    775
12  2005-1-29   9:25    4  ----->  from uper group: 2005-1-23   9:50    4   changed date and min
13  2005-1-29   9:30    775  --->  from uper group: 2005-1-23   9:55    775  changed date and min
14  2005-1-29   9:35    12
15  2005-1-29   9:40    13
16  2005-1-29   9:45    14
17  2005-1-29   9:50    14
18  2005-1-29   9:55    15
19  NaN         9:25    14 -->Since there is no group after '2005-1-29' so you are getting NaN in dates
20  NaN         9:30    15  -->Since there is no group after '2005-1-29' so you are getting NaN in dates
```

If needed use:

```
df=df.dropna(subset=['date'])
```